# Create folder with current date as name in powershell

Tags: date, powershell, directory

I am writing a powershell script. I would like to know how to create a folder with current date as name. The folder name should be "yyyy-MM-dd" (acording to the .NET custom format strings).

I know that to create folder I need to use this command:

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "some path"
```

A possible solution could be (if I want to create the folder in the same directory as the script is:

```
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\$date"
```

Is there a way to chain the commands so I do not need to create the variable?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
```

or as alroc suggested in order to get the same formatting no matter the culture.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. The only problem in your solution is the short date, because it depends on users language. Please, fix it to ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Can't you move? ;)
alroc posted an answer that might work for ya. For me I got exactly what you're looking for and didn't think twice about it.

Comment: I was not sure about the "" and '' and I would like to mark your question as correct.

Comment: I found out that you can also directly get the string from get-date like this: Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `ToShortDateString()` as @notjustme wrote; its formatting is dependent upon locale and your date format settings in the Regional & Language control panel. For example, on my PC right now, that would produce the following directory name:

```
C:\Users\me\09\18\2014
```

Explicitly set the format of the date string instead.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

Comment: I just commented this on @notjustme answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "E:\parent" -Name $FolderName
```

It is creating folder with name **11-06-2020-07-29-41** under **E:\parent**

Answer (score 1):

The shorter way is

`$date = get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Needs to be `-Format yyyy-MM-dd`. mm is minutes not months.

Answer (score 0):

```
$datecurrent = get-date -Format dd-MM-yy

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\$datecurrent"
```