# Create folder with current date as "yyyyMMdd New Folder" in context menu with cmd.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, date, directory, contextmenu

Is there a way of extending the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917637/create-folder-with-current-date-as-name-in-powershell) to include the string " New Folder". e.g. "20221029 New Folder"

Current workaround that I am using in this Registry Key

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\NewFolderWithDate\command
```

is

```
cmd.exe /c powershell New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd  New'))"
```

This works in cmd.exe but with no spaces:

```
powershell New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))NewFolder"
```

Comment: For me it works this way `powershell -NoProfile -Command "& {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path """.\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')) New Folder"""}"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following (note that there is *no* need to call via `cmd /c`):

```bash
powershell "New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path \".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd  New'))\""
```

- Use `\"` to escape `"` characters that you want PowerShell to retain as part of the PowerShell command to execute, after command-line parsing - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for more information.
- Embed the command to pass (to the implied `-Command` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter) *as a whole* in `"..."` so as to prevent whitespace normalization; that is, without it, the *two* spaces before `New` in your command would become *one*.